# Container height adapts to one of its child and the other child adapts to container

Tags: html, css

Example:

```css
.left {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  float: left;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="inner-container">
        <img
          class="left"
          src="http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/incgraph/exaimage-0001.png"
        />
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to make `div.right` to fill 100% of `div.inner-container`'s height?

Here's [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-47is4?file=/styles.css:0-151) if you don't like SO.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float`s and give `display:flex` to parent

```css
.inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img class="left" src="http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/incgraph/exaimage-0001.png" />
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly in chrome, but if you open this code in safari, you'll see that image aspect ratio changed and image becomes stretched vertically. The same effect takes place in blink-powered browsers.

Comment: add `object-fit: contain` to img

Comment: In chrome everything is ok, but Safari now freezes `inner-container`'s height and right div's height is now always same as `inner-container`'s one. The `img` scales, as it was earlier.
https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-lx5ul?file=/styles.css

Comment: okay I will take a look later